# View a graph that is updated each time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of data, and I have an array of time.
These are the arrays:

```js
const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 90, 40, 0, 20],
};
```

After a second I want to display the graph until number 60, after 2.5 seconds the graph until number 85, and so these ...

This is the code I've been trying to do so far, but it's not working for me

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

function App() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState('');
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState('');

  const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 60, 75, 50, 40, 0, 20],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Reps.TimeOfMove.forEach((time, index) => {
      const interval = setInterval(() => setScore(Reps.ScoreOfMove[index]), time * 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    })

  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {score}
      {<Bar
        data={Reps}
        width={100}
        height={50}
        options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
      />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to display different graph bar each time, according to the time it appears.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean  ``setTimeout``

Answer (score 0):

So, time of move differences are 0.5, 1, 2, ... etc. I would use the smallest for the interval to catch all times.

So interval time is 500ms.

Each time interval triggers we can sum the time and have the passed time. Now we can filter the data by the time that has passed.

```
const INTERVAL_TIME = 500;
function App() {
  const [score, setScore] = useState('');
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

  const Reps = {
    TimeOfMove: [1, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4.5, 5, 6, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15.5],
    ScoreOfMove: [60, 85, 42, 60, 70, 80, 60, 75, 50, 40, 0, 20],
  };

  useEffect(() => {
      // TODO: add a max time to stop interval
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
         setCurrentTime((oldTime) => oldTime + INTERVAL_TIME);
      }, INTERVAL_TIME);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
  }, [])
  
  const currentTimeInSec = currentTime/1000;
  // now filter the data
  const chartData = Reps.TimeOfMove.filter((moveTime) => currentTimeInSec <= moveTime).map((moveTime, index) => ({ x: moveTime, y: Reps.ScoreOfMove[index] }))

  return (
    <div>
      {score}
      {<Bar
        data={Reps}
        width={100}
        height={50}
        options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }}
      />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried to run the code, I get the error: `Identifier 'chartData' has already been declared. (28:8)`

Comment: @dustyeav you need to arrange the remainings I just helped with the logic.

Answer (score -1):

for your useCase you need to use `setTimeout` instaed `setIntreval`